# How do I take away the yellow marker from my LineChartView? | iOS charts

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I have created a program with a view that displays a graph. I have done this using a LineChartView from the pod 'Charts'.

Below is a picture of what my graph looks like.

How do I disable the yellow marker, which appears whenever the user touches the view?

[image]

This is my constant.

```
let chartView = LineChartView()
```

I would like something along the lines of

```
chartView.enableYellowMarker = false
```

Could someone fix this or come up with a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable value highlights via

```
chartView.highlightPerTapEnabled = false
```

Comment: It won't show marker though